# Customize sorting for LazyDataModel for specific column

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, customization, lazydatamodel

How can I customize sorting for a `LazyDataModel` for a specific column in `p:dataTable`?

Comment: **in** the load method in your lazyDataModel implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done by overriding [load](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html#load(int,%20int,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.Map)) method ..

thank for all ..

Comment: Please improve this answer. This is a plain copy of my comment... A little improvement of the answer would be nice